# Error during npm install inside project - Mac m1 pro

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to run project local every time when I type the command
`npm install` or `npm ci` I'm getting same error about global variables. In my case, the error involves python or node. Screen shot below.
[image]

I reinstalled python and node several times, added the aliases needed for ./zshrc
My current versions of python and node are posted below in the image.
[image]

I tried with the same result installing `npm install/npm ci` with python 3.9 version
I' working on macbook pro with M1 pro. Thanks in advance for any advice :)

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. Remove `package-lock.json` file.
2. Remove `node_modules` folder.
3. Run `npm i -g npm-check-updates` to install [NPM Check Updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) (`ncu`).
4. Run `ncu -u` to update all dependencies to the latest version.
5. Run `npm i` to reinstall all dependencies.